# Оптимизация скорости кода

Tags: python, оптимизация

Пытаюсь решить задачу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код выполняется без ошибок, но вот при увеличении количества данных скорость снижается и решение не проходит по условию в какой то момент. Помогите оптимизировать код. Возможно есть другой вариант для расчета формулы.

Спасибо.

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.loadtxt('input.txt', skiprows=1)

ar.astype(dtype=np.float16)
ar = ar[ar[:, 0].argsort()]

s = 0
p = 0

un = np.unique(ar[:, 0])

for _ in un:

    for row in ar[ar[:, 0] == _][:, 1]:
        s += (
            ar[np.where((ar[:, 0] > _)
                        & ((ar[:, 1] > row)))].shape[0] +
            ar[np.where((ar[:, 0] > _)
                        & ((ar[:, 1] == row)))].shape[0] / 2
        )
        p += (
            ar[np.where(ar[:, 0] > _)].shape[0]
        )
print(round(s / p, 7))
```

Оптимизировал не много код но дальше уменьшить время не удается.

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.loadtxt('input.txt', skiprows=1)

ar = ar[ar[:, 0].argsort()]

s = 0
p = 0

un = np.unique(ar[:, 0])
un_1, duplicate_count = np.unique(ar, axis=0, return_counts=True)
pivot_table = np.concatenate((un_1, (np.array([duplicate_count])).T), axis=1)

for _ in un:

    for row in pivot_table[pivot_table[:, 0] == _][:, 1]:

        s += (
                (
                        np.sum(pivot_table[np.where((pivot_table[:, 0] > _)
                                                    & (pivot_table[:, 1] > row))][:, 2])
                        + np.sum(pivot_table[np.where((pivot_table[:, 0] > _)
                                                      & (pivot_table[:, 1] == row))][:, 2])
                        / 2
                 )
                * pivot_table[np.where((pivot_table[:, 0] == _) & (pivot_table[:, 1] == row))][:, 2]
        )
        p += (
                np.sum(pivot_table[np.where(pivot_table[:, 0] > _)][:, 2])
                * pivot_table[np.where((pivot_table[:, 0] == _) & (pivot_table[:, 1] == row))][:, 2]
        )
        
print(round(float(s / p), 7))
```

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм квадратичный. И любой алгоритм который сравнивает между собой все пары записей будет таким, как бы вы его не оптимизировали.

Быстрое решение основано на алгоритме подсчёта количества инверсий в перестановке/массиве - модификация сортировки слиянием считает число инверсий за NlogN. Суммарное число инверсий нам не интересно, но для каждого элемента массива можно сосчитать сколько элементов меньших его стоит перед ним.

Входные пары `(t_i, y_i)` сортируются по `t_i` (если несколько `t_i` равны, то `y_i` упорядочиваются по убыванию) и дополняются двумя счётчиками:

> ```
> t_i - точное значение
> y_i - предсказанное значение
> lt_i - число элементов, стоящих перед текущим, таких что `y` меньше текущего
> eq_i - число элементов, стоящих перед текущим, таких что `y` равен текущему
> ```

Сортировка слиянием по списку записей упорядоченных по `t_i` строит список записей упорядоченных по `y_i`.

`lt_i` считается в два прохода: сперва в сортировке слиянием подсчитываются меньшие либо равные элементы, затем из них вычитается количество равных.
`eq_i` считает в один проход по уже упорядоченному списку.

Обладая счётчиками `lt_i` и `eq_i` можно вычислить ROC-AUC за линейное время.

Суммарная сложность алгоритма NlogN. У меня нет доступа проверяющей системе, я сравнивал работу вашего решения со своим на случайных наборах данных. Проверялись как наборы уникальных значений, так и повторяющиеся. Во всех случаях ROC-AUC совпадал в первых шести знаках.

Наибольшие трудности доставила обработка повторяющихся `t_i` и `y_i` в различных сочетаниях. Я опущу подробности, их слишком много.

```
def merge(a, b):
    c = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i][1] <= b[j][1]:
            c.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            b[j][2] += i
            c.append(b[j])
            j += 1
    while i < len(a):
        c.append(a[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(b):
        b[j][2] += i
        c.append(b[j])
        j += 1
    return c


def merge_sort(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a
    h = len(a) // 2
    a1 = merge_sort(a[:h])
    a2 = merge_sort(a[h:])
    return merge(a1, a2)


def fill_counters(a):
    a = merge_sort(a)

    prev_y = None
    c_y = 0
    for e in a:
        if e[1] == prev_y:
            c_y += 1
        else:
            c_y = 0
        e[2] -= c_y
        prev_y = e[1]

    prev_y = None
    c_y = 0
    c_t = 0
    prev_t = None
    for e in a:
        if e[1] == prev_y:
            c_y += 1
            if e[0] != prev_t:
                c_t = c_y
        else:
            c_y = 0
            c_t = 0
        e[3] = c_t
        prev_y = e[1]
        prev_t = e[0]


def main():
    array = [
        [float(t) for t in input().split()] + [0, 0]
        for _ in range(int(input()))
    ]
    array.sort(key=lambda e: (e[0], -e[1]))
    fill_counters(array)

    n = 0
    d = 0
    k = 0
    prev_t = None
    for i, e in enumerate(array):
        if e[0] != prev_t:
            k = i
        n += e[2] + e[3] / 2
        d += k
        prev_t = e[0]
    print(n / d)


main()
```

Времена выполнения:

> ```
> размер   разница  время       время
> списка   ROC-AUC  работы      работы
>    (N)            NumPy (c)   merge_sort (с)
>                    
>  10000  0.000000      3.794     0.119
>  20000  0.000000     13.699     0.225
>  30000  0.000000     27.586     0.318
>  40000  0.000000     48.019     0.460
>  50000  0.000000     75.546     0.643
>  60000  0.000000    106.449     0.717
>  70000  0.000000    149.666     0.892
>  80000  0.000000    183.675     0.922
>  90000  0.000000    230.494     1.073
> 100000  0.000000    303.946     1.214
> ```

**P.S.** `print(round(s / p, 7))` - печатать округлённые значения лучше форматированием. Вещественные десятичные дроби не представляются точно в компьютере. Вы рискуете напечатать неокруглённый результат. Так лучше: `print(f'{s / p:.7f}')`.